# Javascript not rendering in partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a modal with a form in it for creating an object and a modal for updating the data in an object. For some reason the javascript for the create object modal is working but the update modal is not rendering the applications javascript. I am not really sure why this would be happening. Below is my code:

#### index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@suggested_invite, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <div class="modal fade" id="mynewsuggestedinvite" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        Modal with form in it
      </div>
  <% end %>
<tbody id="content"><%= render @suggested_invites %></tbody>\\ Where the 
list of objects exists and where the modal that shows the objects exists
```

#### _suggested_invite.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@suggested_invite, :method => :put, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div class="modal fade" id="mynewsuggestedinvite" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    Modal with form filled out with object data
  </div>
```

#### dashboard.js.erb

```
$(document).ready(function(){

Javascript Code

});
```

The Javascript in dashboard.js.erb only works in index.html.erb and not _suggested_invite.html.erb. I would like to have the dashboard.js.erb javascript code work in both the partial and in the main page. Any help would be very much appreciated! Let me know if there is any more information I can provide

Comment: does it work in partial when you refresh the page? do you render partial and main view in same view?

Comment: @KcUS_unico It does not work when I refresh the page. And yes, I render the partial and main view in the same view

Comment: Both of your modals have the same `id`, I'm willing to bet you're referencing each modal by `$("#mynewsuggestedinvite")` which will only ever find the first one.

Comment: @XMLSlayer You are absolutely right